# JWPlayer doesn’t throw error when Live Stream is stopped or Network disconnect

Tags: jwplayer, live-streaming, jwplayer6

I am using JWPlayer 6 (web player) to play live streaming videos.

When live stream broadcaster stops streaming or there is internet disconnection, the JWPlayer freezes on last frame of video but does not throw error. It does not fire jwplayer().on('error') event.

Ideally it should start showing swirling circle, and fire the on("error") event. Which is correctly happening in non-live-streaming scenario.

This is exact similar situation which is asked on JWPlayer support site at https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/questions/16266595-jwplayer-doesn-t-throw-error-when-chunklist-is-not-found-4-4-stream-stopped-network-disconnect?new=16266595 
But no solution is offered there.

Comment: What's your source for the live videos?  RTMP?  HLS?  What browser/version?  Remember that JWPlayer is at the mercy of the underlying browser/Flash implementation.

Comment: its HLS (format=m3u8-aapl-v3). Checked with Chrome and Firefox both have same issue. and I am using flash implementation of JWPlayer 6

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following Tatami for Online Video snapshot which is using "Streamy" to provide elegant stream detection in JW Player:

http://dev.powered-by-haiku.co.uk/solutions/tatami/?share=dhoAJvxfYW

If you click on the "Media source" component you can modify the "URL to HLS source:" to point to your stream and you can also change the poster image URL.

You can also change the background image of the Streamy overlay by clicking on the config icon (the "cog" in the top right) > Preview Settings > Additional CSS.

Clicking on the "play" icon in the "Player Setup" component will show a preview of the configuration - which will allow you to check how it reacts to your stream coming online / going offline.

This snapshot will render in JW7 by default but you can switch to JW6 using the player solution icons up in the top right of the toolbar.